# how do an android viewflipper but with iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, viewflipper

i need to implement two different views, one for a map and the other for a list. And that i want is to switch the view to the other when we click on a button. I know how we can do with two different views that we hide, but i want that like with the viewflipper for android the views switched like one view which is split into two like this :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZTiJmclaRc

Thx.

ps: sorry for my english, i'm not very fluent in english.

Comment: UIScrollView? UIAnimation with Slide transition?

Comment: I don't know if there is a problem if we put just one view and one table view. In fact i need to custom the table view with data that i retrieve on internet. That's why i have a class for the table view, so i need two different controllers, but i don't know if it is possible to have a link like you say with two views in the same controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CATransition` to achieve this sort of effect quite easily. For example:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.delegate = self;
animation.duration = 0.3f;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transition"];

// swap out your views here - either add / remove subviews or show / hide subviews
[self.view addSubview:otherView];
```

When animating the other way, change the `subtype` to `kCATransitionFromLeft`.

You'll also need to link to the `QuartzCore` framework, and import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: if there is no other solution, i'll test to do like that. I hope it will be ok.

Comment: If you have an other idea for do this, i'll be gratefull to know.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010891-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1), a working example you can download here:
[How to Use UIPageViewController to Build Tutorial Screens](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

It looks what you are looking for.

Comment: No, i need to stay on the same page, because i use data for annotations on my mapView and for the tableView at the same time. It is quicker to stay in the page than in two different page.

Comment: Maybe i have misunderstand, i think it is a good solution if we could implement a map and a tableview

Comment: Do you think it is possible to switch the action ? i mean, it is possible to change the fact that the user slide to switch the different page by a button which allow to switch to the other view ?